# Is there something for Visual Studio that can let my team developer Blackberry applications?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, blackberry

Is there anything blackberry related that can be used in Visual Studio 2010?|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio to develop rich [Web Application](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/) for the Blackberry Smartphone.

There's no way to develop blackberry native Apps using visual studio. For native apps you have two choices:

1) [Blackberry JDE](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp) (Java Development Environment)
A swing IDE specialized for Blackberry development. It is a bit heavy, it miss lot of cool features (refactoring, svn integration) but it does the job. It is really usefull in the process of "signing" your application with RIM

2) [Eclipse Plugin](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp) 
IMHO this is a better choice for development, you'll get all the benefits of eclipse and a nice Blackberry emulator

Comment: Isn't the JDE based on Eclipse as well? As such it should be possible to install any missing features as plugins.

Comment: The JDE is not based on Eclipse, it is a fully standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

you can see all the required information here

http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/